# How can I set text left to the edit text programatically?

Tags: android

I just want to set the TextView to left of the edit text programatically.i searched a lot,i didn't find the solution yet and i don't what is my mistake.

here is my code:

```
        LinearLayout ll_text = new LinearLayout(this);
            LayoutParams ll_text_params = new LayoutParams(width,
                    height);
            ll_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ll_text.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll_text.setId(Integer.parseInt(question_id));
            //idOfRel++;

            TextView tv_question_text = new TextView(this);
            LayoutParams text_question_params = new LayoutParams(
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            text_question_params.setMargins(Math.round(82 * multiplier), 0,
                    Math.round(82 * multiplier), 0);
            tv_question_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            tv_question_text.setId(Integer.parseInt(question_id));
            tv_question_text.setTextSize(30.0f);
            tv_question_text.setText(question_no+"."+getTitleString(question_id, tv_question_text));
            tv_question_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv_question_text.setTypeface(nexa_bold);

            TextView tv_at=new TextView(this);
            LayoutParams tv_at_params=new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tv_at_params.setMargins(Math.round(20*multiplier),0, Math.round(290*multiplier),0);
            tv_at_params.topMargin = Math.round(30 * multiplier);
            tv_at.setId(6);
            tv_at.setText("@");
            tv_at.setTextSize(40.0f);



            ActionEditText et_text = new ActionEditText(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et_text_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    Math.round(472 * multiplier), Math.round(63 * multiplier));
    //      et_text_params.setMargins(Math.round(30*multiplier),0, Math.round(270*multiplier), 0);
            et_text_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 6);
            et_text.setId(1);
            et_text.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            et_text.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40) });
            et_text.setHint("Twitter Name");
            et_text.setSingleLine(true);
            et_text.setPaddingRelative(15, 0, 15, 0);
            et_text.setTextSize(20.0f);
            et_text.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

need help thanks in advance..

[image]

like this..

Comment: By default EditText will have text alignment left. Why are you trying to set to left. Can you provide a screen shot of the EditText?

Comment: my mistake...that is textView not text...i mean i want to set that text view left of the edit text...like we do in xml android:layout_leftOf="@+id/et_text"

Comment: Here you are using two textviews, which one you want to place left?

Comment: Tell something about your expected output so that I can give you a solution.

Comment: ll_text is my linear layout where i am going to add three views.(two text views and edit text),one text view will be on the top and another text view  and edit text will be kept below the first text view.                                          like:                      1.TextView                                                                                         2                   2,Textview and edit text

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your editText:

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one more LinearLayout below the first TextView and add both the second TextView and EditText to this LinearLayout. Like this:

```
LinearLayout ll_text = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams ll_text_params = new LayoutParams(width,
            height);
    ll_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ll_text.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll_text.setId(Integer.parseInt(question_id));
    //idOfRel++;

    TextView tv_question_text = new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams text_question_params = new LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text_question_params.setMargins(Math.round(82 * multiplier), 0,
            Math.round(82 * multiplier), 0);
    tv_question_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    tv_question_text.setId(Integer.parseInt(question_id));
    tv_question_text.setTextSize(30.0f);
    tv_question_text.setText(question_no+"."+getTitleString(question_id, tv_question_text));
    tv_question_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv_question_text.setTypeface(nexa_bold);

    TextView tv_at=new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams tv_at_params=new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv_at_params.setMargins(Math.round(20*multiplier),0, Math.round(290*multiplier),0);
    tv_at_params.topMargin = Math.round(30 * multiplier);
    tv_at.setId(6);
    tv_at.setText("@");
    tv_at.setTextSize(40.0f);



    ActionEditText et_text = new ActionEditText(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et_text_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            Math.round(472 * multiplier), Math.round(63 * multiplier));
//      et_text_params.setMargins(Math.round(30*multiplier),0, Math.round(270*multiplier), 0);
        et_text_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 6);
        et_text.setId(1);
        et_text.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        et_text.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40) });
        et_text.setHint("Twitter Name");
        et_text.setSingleLine(true);
        et_text.setPaddingRelative(15, 0, 15, 0);
        et_text.setTextSize(20.0f);
        et_text.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    //Additional Code to your code

    LinearLayout innerContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams innerContainerParams = new LayoutParams(match_parent, wrap_content);
    innerContainerParams.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    innerContainer.addView(tv_at);
    innerContainer.addView(et_text);

    ll_text.addView(tv_question_text);
    ll_text.addView(innerContainer);
```

I guess you looking for something like this.

```
et_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.myDrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, up vote this answer.